# unique value of a cosmos container using EF Core 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I am using EF core as my ORM to use Azure Cosmos DB. I want to have the `Email` field unique.
I tried to use this but it didn't work and I can add records with same email.:

[image: for instance I could add 2 records with the same email]

This is how I set the db context:

```
var userModel = modelBuilder.Entity<User>();

userModel.ToContainer(nameof(Users))
    .HasNoDiscriminator()
    .HasKey(u => u.UserId);

userModel.Property(u => u.ETag).IsETagConcurrency();
userModel.HasIndex(u => u.Email).IsUnique();
```

Comment: _"but it didn't work"_ ; could you provide more info? Error's? Behaviour?

Comment: @Stefan I added a picture of the problem

Comment: Not an answer, but [How unique is Azure Cosmos DB Unique Keys](https://h-savran.blogspot.com/2019/08/how-unique-is-azure-cosmos-db-unique.html)